# is it possible to define a pointer to a row in linq to sql?

Tags: c#, database, linq-to-sql

Is it possible to define a pointer to a row in the database so I could retrieve that row, the next row, and the previous row without querying the database?

Comment: If you use your initial query to populate a DataSet, you can do whatever you want with it. However, I'm wondering what it is that you're really trying to accomplish since this is rarely necessary or advisable.

Comment: ?  You want to read the database without a query to the database?  call me confused.

Comment: @David Lively I want to get the next row or the previous row without a query so the retrieval will be fast

Comment: @Mark Schultheiss I want to query it only once and then to keep the pointer to the row I found so I can use it to get the next row for example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You need to query all three rows in one query and put them into a list. You can then index the list without doing another query.